How does the light from distant stars change for an observer at the center of the collapsing or falling sphere?
At the center of a spherically symmetric thin solid static shell lies a point observer. For this observer, distant stars appear violet shifted slightly more $\frac{{G \cdot M}}{{{c^2} \cdot r}}$ ($\frac{{G \cdot M}}{{{c^2} \cdot r}}$ is for an observer on the surface of the sphere). The initial radius of the shell is much larger than the Schwarzschild gravitational radius ($r \gg {r_{\rm{g}}} = 2\frac{{G \cdot M}}{{{c^2}}}$). The shell instantly (simultaneously across the entire sphere from the center's perspective) changes its structure from solid to non-interacting cold dust (without emitting radiation to simplify the problem). The dust begins to accelerate and fall towards the sphere center.
For the observer at the sphere center, will the second derivative of the violet shift with respect to time appear at the same moment when he sees the transition of the sphere from solid to dust? Or slightly earlier by approximately $<\frac{r}{c}$?
How will the light from distant stars further change for the observer at the center when the circumference of the sphere reaches approximately $2 \cdot \pi  \cdot \frac{{2 \cdot G \cdot M}}{{{c^2}}}$? And how will light change further?
Distant stars are assumed to be stationary.
The question is within the framework of General Relativity without considering quantum effects or strings or microscopic inhomogeneities.

Initial size is $r\gg r_g$. The observer is at the center. Initially the observer can exist. The main part of the question is about $r > r_g$ and $r$ near $r_g$.

OK, I see what you are getting at now. Indeed it is a complex problem since static metrics can no longer be used.
